# Java Stream collect after flatMap returns List<Object> instead of List<String>

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I tried the following code using Java 8 streams:

```
Arrays.asList("A", "B").stream()
            .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList("X", "Y").stream().map(s1 -> s + s1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I get is a `List<Object>` while I would expect a `List<String>`. If I remove the collect and I try:

```
Arrays.asList("A", "B").stream().flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList("X", "Y").stream().map(s1 -> s + s1));
```

I correctly get a `Stream<String>`.

Where am I wrong? Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The problem is due to Eclipse (now using Kepler SR2 with java 8 patch 1.0.0.v20140317-1956). The problem does non appear if compiling using javac or, as commented by Holger, using Netbeans

Comment: Not for me. It returns `Stream<String>`. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Holger, I am compiling inside Eclipse

Comment: Well, the Java 8 support of Eclipse is still in development but I suggest you carefully check whether the code you have written inside Eclipse matches what you have written here, before blaming Eclipse as it doesn’t look like a tricky language construct (compiler corner case) to me. With `Kepler SR2` and `JDT Patch with Java 8 1.0.0.v20140317-1956` it works correctly.

Comment: @Holger, you were right about the stream, I have updated my question, apparently the problem is not in the Stream but in the collect which I had initally removed to (over)simplify my question

Comment: Ok, *now* it looks like an Eclipse problem. With `Netbeans` you can correctly collect into a `List<String>`

Comment: @Holger, thank you, I edited the question to underline that the problem is limited to Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type inference is a new feature. Until tools and IDEs are fully developed I recommend using explicitly typed lambdas. There ware cases where Eclipse even crashed if an explicit cast was missing, but that is fixed now.

Here's a workaround:

With a typed "s1":

```
asList.stream()
   .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList("X", "Y").stream().map((String s1) -> s + s1))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or with a genric parameter:

```
asList.stream()
   .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList("X", "Y").stream().<String>map(s1 -> s + s1))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The same is true if you add the parameter before `flatMap` instead of `map`.

But I suggest you use `s::concat`:

```
asList.stream()
   .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList("X", "Y").stream().map(s::concat))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```